# Mongoose populate return undefined

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm currently trying to develop an app using mongo and node.js.

I am facing a problem when I want to build a query who use the populate option.

Here are my Schemas :

```
// Schema used by mongoose
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
   _id:        mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   login:      String,
   password:   String,
   movies:     [ { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: movieModel} ],
   admin:      Boolean
},{ collection: "user" });

var movieSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
   _id:           mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   title:         String,
}, { collection: "movie" });
```

As you can see, each user have an array of movies, this array contains valid ids of movies. What I want is to have the movies of an user. This is how I build my query :

```
var query = userModel.findOne({ login: req.session.user["login"] })
                        .populate("movies");

query.exec(function(err, user)
{
   if (err)
      throw err;

   console.log(user.movies[0].title);
});
```

The query is executed successfully, but when I try to display the title of the first movie at the console.log line I got an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined". I checked the documentation of mongoose and don't understand why I'm getting this error.

I would like to specify that my database contains valid data.
I put mongoose in debug mode, and this is the query that is executed :

```
Mongoose: user.findOne({ login: 'user' }) { fields: undefined }  
Mongoose: user.find({ _id: { '$in': [ ObjectId("52e2a28949ad409834473e71"), ObjectId("52e2a28949ad409834473e79") ] } }) { fields: undefined }
```

The two ids on the second line are valid ids of movies. I would like to display their name.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the value of this: `ref: movieModel`?

`movieModel` would need to be set to the string like `"Movie"`. See [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) for more information. It will need to match the identifier provided when you create the `Movie` model.

```
var Movie = mongoose.model('Movie', movieSchema);
```

So, you might have in a schema:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    favorite_movies: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Movie' }
});
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

I've used the string `Movie` in both the `Schema` definition and when creating the `Movie` type. They need to be exactly the same.

MongooseJs uses the string name of the `Model` to determine where to fetch the documents from when using `ref` and `populate`.

In the debug output, you can see how Mongoose is actually querying the wrong collection, as I'd expect it to be using `movies.find` to find the relevant `Movie` documents.

Comment: Thanks for your answer WiredPrairie,

I change my userSchema like you said :
**movies:     [ { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "movieModel" } ]**

Now I am facing a new error :
**"throw new MongooseError.MissingSchemaError(name);
MongooseError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "movieModel"**

I don't know what is going on here :(

Comment: You didn't make the change correctly I think. The string you use in `ref` needs to exactly match the name used to register the model. Maybe: `"Movie"` for example.

Comment: No I'm sure that my string is correct. I am defining my model like this :
var movieModel = mongoose.model("movie", movieSchema);

This really bothers me as I don't understand where does this problem come from.

I was wondering, did my problem is linked with the way that I insert data in my database ? Currently I put all my data in a js file in the JSON format. And I insert them by typing in the command line : mongo datafile.js
Do I need to use mongoose to insert data ? Sorry if my question seems stupid but this is the very first app I am building using mongoDB, mongoose and nodejs.
Thank you

Comment: See my update ..., as it sounds like you aren't matching the strings still. It's hard to say whether the rest is done correctly though. You don't need to use Mongoose to insert data -- as long as the data matches the Schema defined in Mongoose ... otherwise Mongoose will ignore other fields defined for example.

Comment: Finally I got it.
Thanks a lot !